# Type of Intel Broadwell processor that supports 16 COS registers

Tags: intel, cpu-registers, cpu-architecture, cpu-cache

As far as I know, the Intel Processor D (previously called Broadwell processor) can support at most 16 COS registers for the [cache allocation technology](http://wiki.xenproject.org/wiki/Intel_Platform_QoS_Technologies#Cache_Allocation_Technology). So I want to purchase a computer that has 16 COS registers on its Intel CPU.

According to [Intel's manual](http://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/manuals/64-ia-32-architectures-software-developers-manual.pdf), the maximum number of COS registers is stored in the lower 16 bits of the EDX register as the output of the `CPUID.(EAX=10H, ECX=ResID=1)` instruction.

**My question is:**

Does anyone know which type of Intel Processor D can support 16 COS registers?

(If you happen to have a Processor D processor, I really appreciate it if you could run the `cpuid` instruction and post the output of the cpuid.)

**Does anyone know if Intel Xeon E5-2683v4 has 16 COS registers?** 
I plan to get this expensive processor, but I really don't want to waste $2K just because it does not have 16 COS registers. :-(

I'm not that sure if this question is suitable for this forum. If not, could you let me know which forum I should ask? (I actually think this forum should have the most expert to solve this question. In addition, this question is really related to the system programming, because it determines the hardware capability the system software can utilize. :-) )

BTW, I asked on Intel 01.org one week ago, no one replies... :-(
I really don't want to buy a computer and find out it does not have what I need. :-(

Answer (score 1):

[Intel Xeon D-1540 CPUID dump, CPUID.(EAX=10H, ECX=ResID=1).EDX = 0x0000000F](http://users.atw.hu/instlatx64/GenuineIntel0050662_BroadwellDE_CPUID.txt)

[Intel Xeon E5-2696 v4 CPUID dump, CPUID.(EAX=10H, ECX=ResID=1).EDX = 0x0000000F](http://users.atw.hu/instlatx64/GenuineIntel00406F1_BroadwellE_CPUID2.txt)

[Intel Xeon E5-2697 v4 CPUID dump, CPUID.(EAX=10H, ECX=ResID=1).EDX = 0x0000000F](http://users.atw.hu/instlatx64/GenuineIntel00406F1_BroadwellE_CPUID4.txt)